# Paypal Pro create recurring profile

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-subscriptions

I am creating Paypal Pro recurring profile with `CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile`. I am confused of what recurring variables I need to use for the following billing conditions:

1. Trial Period: First 15 days user will be charged nothing.
2. On Second Month: user will be charged $30.
3. From third Month every odd month:  user will be charged of $40 per month.
4. From third Month every even month:  user will be charged of $30 per month.

Paypal allows to set multiple trial/billing periods, frequency or amounts? I.e. `trialbillingperiod1`,`trialbillingfrequency1` or `trialamt1`

Comment: I'm having similar problem but none of the documents seem to guide in proper direction. Anyone?